# Including php in html

Tags: php, html

This is an HTML scrip that I created. I am trying to include a php script that contains a variable named $url which has a picture url in it. When I echo the var out, it displays nothing. What am I doing wrong?

```
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">



</head>
<body>


<?php 

include("script.php"); 

?>


<img src= "<?php echo $url; ?>">

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What are the contents of `script.php` ?

Comment: script.php has a var $url that is equal to a url. The script just echos the value. $url = http://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo3w.png

Comment: What is the source code of the page displayed when you try your script on your web browser?

Comment: <?php

$url = "http://www.google.com/images//srpr/logo3w.png"

echo $url;

?>

Comment: Check out Boldewyn's answer below then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually your server is not configured to execute PHP code in HTML files.

The files with name `.php` are handled specially by your web server, i.e., executed as PHP programs.

It goes like this:

```
Browser asks for file
            |
            v
Server looks at found file
    |               |
    v               v
  .html ?         .php ?
    |               |
    v               v
 send it to     give it to
 the browser    PHP and send,
 as-is          what returns
```

You must rename your .html file to .php in order for PHP to work in the server's default configuration.

Comment: It Worked! Thank you very much Boldewyn! Thank you all for helping me out.

Comment: You're welcome. There's [a small tutorial](http://www.php.net/manual/en/tutorial.requirements.php) over at PHP.net, that's actually quite nice to get you started.

Answer (score 0):

Since in the script.php you have the var $url equal to a url. I guess you dont support php. You should install xamp or wamp for localhost.

To test it change the code to this

```
<img src= "<?php echo "http://www.google.com//images/srpr/logo3w.png"; ?>">
```

and check if this is working, if not simple install xamp it will install php, apache and mysql :)

Comment: The php script runs fine, but it does not work in html. How would I install xamp or wamp? Could it be a parsing error?

Comment: Here is the xamp site http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html. Just install the right distribution. Because it should work if you define the right path to image,then the only option is not to support php. Check the updated answer :)

Comment: Putting the link in directly just displayed "> It did not work. Thank you all for the help! I will try xamp.

Comment: I already have Apache and MySQL. The php script works online, so would it be safe to say that php is already supported? I read up that editing the Apache handlers would get it to work. Would this help?

Answer (score 0):

Provide the full URL.

In the included file, change to:

```
$url = "http://www.google.com//images/srpr/logo3w.png";
```

Comment: Read comments on other posts. You need to add handler for PHP in Apache configuration file. Install XAMPP, as Even Johnson suggests.

Comment: Thrustmaster, I already have Apache, and have already tried to add the folling lines to it with no success:
RemoveHandler .shtml .html .htm
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php .htm .html .shtml